# Combining a hamburger menu (sliding in from right) with an accordion style menu

Tags: css, menu, accordion

I'm trying to create a menu that combines actions of a certain hamburger menu with actions of a certain accordion menu.  In particular, I'm interested in combining the following 2 menus:  https://codepen.io/facebookads__/pen/rNWNvee   and   https://jsfiddle.net/esedic/oza6v6px/   (where the text (and hover attributes) in the accordion menu would replace the simple list of 4 items in the hamburger menu).   Have spent the last couple of days sort of doing "mashups" of the 2, but unfortunately not getting very far as my CSS/HTML/Javascript knowledge is on a very basic level.

For instance, I tried replacing the list items (

) in the hamburger menu (below)

```
<body>
    <nav role='navigation'>
        <div id="menuToggle">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <ul id="menu">
                <a href="#">
                    <li>Home</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <li>Portfolio</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <li>About</li>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

with the entire  html in the accordion menu

Would appreciate if anyone could set me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all.  I think I figured it out. Here is the solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/zce9j78x/

```
<body>
    <nav role='navigation'>
        <div id="menuToggle">
            <input type="checkbox" />
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <ul id="menu">
                <a href="#">
                    <li></li>
          
          <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

But now another question.  How can I prevent the scrollbar from appearing later on, which appears a little to jumpy for me? (I guess, the question would then be how would I make the original menu that slides in at full height, so scrollbar wouldn't be necessary?) Thanks.

Comment: I answered my 2nd question as well.  Solution is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/qgud9730/

I added following to the body section of the CSS:   

    overflow: hidden;   


Thanks.